# Max stack call size exceeded using ChartJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

I'm trying to graph a lot of points using a line graph through ChartJs. It graphs correctly at 600000000 values and under (6E8), but anything over that will not graph. But I need to graph at least 50E8 values. I've been searching for a setting in the options, or ticks portions of ChartJs documentation and haven't been able to find it at all. Below is my code

```
    <div id="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        var options = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: {{ labels | safe }},
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'Value',
                    data: {{ values | safe }},
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    order: 2
                },
                {
                    label: 'Peak value',
                    data: [{
                    x: {{ labels2[0] | safe }},
                    y: {{ values2[0] | safe }}
                    }, {
                    x: {{ labels2[1] | safe }},
                    y: {{ values2[1] | safe }}
                    }, {
                    x: {{ labels2[2] | safe }},
                    y: {{ values2[2] | safe }}
                    }],
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    showLine: false,
                    order: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much way around it I found out. I had to pass in less than 300k values at a time. To do this I just did a simple

```
if (len(list) > 300000)
    del list[::8]
```

or whatever value you would like.